# How did Google images normalize the width of each row?

Tags: image, math, image-processing

It's easy to resize images so that they all have the same height while maintaining the aspect ratio, but how did they fit them all on a row such that every row has the same width? Did they crop some of the images or what?

Comment: If I can give you a tip on asking questions in a more general, and better way. Your phrasing here is not great. Why not ask a question and hence is likely to be closed or argumentative or just generally useless for a wide audience. Why not say something like 'How can I organise images ...' and generalise the interesting thing you have noticed into a specific set of problems or problem that you yourself don't know how to solve. In this way, the question is more useful, and perhaps you don't even need to ask it, because you solve it yourself via analysis.

Comment: @silky: What's the difference between asking "how can I organize images in this way" and "how did google organize images in this way"? Phrasing might not be perfect, but I think I got the point of the question across, no? Heck, I even went through the trouble of adding an image to make it clear. I'm not having a specific problem; I just stumbled across it earlier today and found it interesting. Might want to use that layout in a future project.

Comment: I shouldn't have to explain it to you; to be honest I can't fathom how you can't understand what I'm trying to say, and I don't care to spend my time explaining it to you. I will not continue to discuss the matter, or any other, with you. I leave it at that.

Comment: @silky: Perhaps your phrasing here is not so great ;)

Answer (score 4):

Remember in google images (apart from cropping) -

1. Spacing between images are not always exactly same.
2. Height of all images in a row are also not always same.

Using above 2 techniques i.e. tweaking the spaces between images and changing size of image little bit by compromising height you can achieve this. In fact the the justify paragraph option in the text editor also use the spacing technique. They evenly distribute the extra spacing between all word.

You don't always get a good spacing in google image search. See this -

[alt text http://dailycoding.com/filesharing/Google_image_search.jpg](http://dailycoding.com/filesharing/Google_image_search.jpg)

Comment: It really doesn't look like a simple "justify" would do the trick. 90% of the rows seem to have perfectly even spacing, and those smaller images are just oddballs - do you think Google intentionally left those in to make the rest of the images fit better? Ruins the appeal IMO.

Answer (score 2):

they actually figure it out through an algorithm to put images next to eachother so with the padding and everything they end up being the same width then they cache that page for the keyword you searched for!

Comment: You say that authoritatively -- what's your source?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very interesting article while looking for the same thing. If you look at google images you can see not all of the rows have the same height. but all the images in a row have the same height. So what you want to do is calculate the right height you need for the row so the images will fit (the images stretch if they get higher or lower). This article will possible help

http://blog.vjeux.com/2012/image/image-layout-algorithm-google-plus.html